# ko.mapping seems to destroy my model

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to use an interface, and populate a class based on that interface (Model: IModel) from a WebAPI call, which returns a .Net class structure. My interface matches the structure, names and types.

Knockout view model code.

interface IReferenceItem {
        id: number;
        text: string;
    }

```
interface IModel {
    ID: KnockoutObservable<number>;
    HasPromotion: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;
    DebtPaymentTypeId: KnockoutObservable<number>;
    Description: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    DueDayOfMonth: KnockoutObservable<number>;
    OpeningBalance: KnockoutObservable<number>;
    StandardRate: KnockoutObservable<number>;
    MinimumMonthlyPercentage: KnockoutObservable<number>;
    MinimumMonthlyPayment: KnockoutObservable<number>;
    PromotionEndDate: KnockoutObservable<Date>;
    PromotionalRate: KnockoutObservable<number>;
}

class DebtViewModel {

    PaymentTypes: KnockoutObservableArray<IReferenceItem>;
    DaysOfMonth: KnockoutObservableArray<IReferenceItem>;

    LoadedState: KnockoutObservable<boolean> = ko.observable(false);
    Model: IModel;

    constructor() {
        var self = this;

        $.get("/api/debt/1")
            .done((data) => {
                self.Model = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
                console.debug(data);
                console.debug(self.Model.Description());
                alert(self.Model.ID());
                self.LoadedState(true);
            });


        this.PaymentTypes = ko.observableArray([{ "id": 1, "text": "Fixed Amount" }, { "id": 2, "text": "Percentage based" }])
        this.DaysOfMonth = ko.observableArray([{ "id": 1, "text": "1st" }, { "id": 2, "text": "2nd" }, { "id": 3, "text": "3rd" }])

        ko.computed(() => {
            if (self.LoadedState()) {
                alert(self.Model.ID());
            }
        });
    }

    save = function () {
        alert("Save Model back to the POST API call....");
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(new DebtViewModel());
```

I am trying to map the data from the api call, to my Model class.

`data`, after the api call, has valid data.

But it seems outside of the constructor, this.Model is always 'Undefined'. I think it's because I am not initialising it correctly (Before the Get?).

It seems my Model vanishes... or gets changed.

On the line, `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this.Model);`, this.Model is undefined, as on subsequent lines.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe what you mean is `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, this.Model, this);`

Comment: data is the model I get from the api call, this is the viewmodel, and this.Model is the model I want to hold all my ui data. I've kind of split out the data from the view model, so that I can just post that back on save. So I don't thing this is right.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor you're declaring a *local* variable self, which will receive the results of the api call.

Anywhere outside this constructor however, this local variable won't be accessible. Referring to `this.Model` won't refer to this local variable, but to the class property `Model`.

You're already using an arrow function, so I guess you could try this:

```
class DebtViewModel {

    ...
    Model: IModel;

    constructor() {
        $.get("/api/debt/1")
            .done((data) => {
                this.Model = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
            });
        ...
    }

    save() {
        var myModel = this.Model;
        alert("Save Model back to the POST API call....");
    }
}
```